# How to create a loop of web driver instance variables depending on length of accounts I have through python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a program that I need to open multiple chrome browsers for each account that I have so for example:

```
accounts = ["account 1", "account 2", "account 3", "account 4"]
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver3 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver4 = webdriver.Chrome()
```

This code works and does what I ultimately want it to do which is open multiple instances of chrome web drivers for each account that I have. However, it is static and if I want to add additional accounts, I need to go back and manually add in additional chrome driver variables. How can I change this into a for loop?

For example:

```
For i in range(0, len(accounts)-1):
     driveri = webdriver.Chrome()
```

How do I rephrase the above code to something that can work?

Answer (score 0):

With better data structure you can do it like this.

```
accounts = {
    "account 1": 3,
    "account 2": 5
}

drivers = {
    "account 1": [],
    "account 2": []
}

for key, value in accounts.items():
    temp_driver = [webdriver.Chrome() for i in range(0, value)]
    drivers[key] = temp_driver

## Add new account and number of browser you want to open for that new account
new_account_name = "account 10"
accounts[new_account_name] = 15
new_drivers = [webdriver.Chrome() for i in range(0, accounts[new_account_name])]
drivers[new_account_name] = new_drivers
```